# How to sync new s3 objects to other s3 account using lambda javascript/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using aws-sdk and lambda with javascript.

using this listObjectV2 and copyObject, I'm able to copy the objects from the other account, but I think this s3.copyObject, copy ALL the objects including new objects.

I just want to copy/transfer file only for new and updated objects.
Its like the cli the aws sync.

Comment: You'd need to write it yourself. What have you tried and what issue are you currently facing? An alternative approach is to have S3 trigger an AWS Lambda function whenever an object is created/updated. The Lambda function could then copy that file to another location. This copies the files immediately after creation rather than doing it as a batch.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already did that trigger but I think its expensive when it come to trigger/invoke it every new files. 

I do it manually by using CLI,
but now I want automatically sync using lambda/node.js.

Here's my reference 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to copy just any ongoing changes, you can use [S3 replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-how-setup.html)

> Objects that existed before you set up replication aren't replicated automatically. In other words, Amazon S3 doesn't replicate objects retroactively.

[Here is an instruction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-walkthrough-2.html) how to setup the cross account replication